# отключение ftp авторизации в windows server

Tags: windows, сервер, веб-сервер, iis, ftp-сервер

Мне нужно отключить авторизацию на ftp сервере, чтобы делать прямые ссылки на скачивание файла. Я пытался делать ссылки, включающие логин и пароль, но  браузер все равно просит авторизацию.
Анонимный доступ не помогает, все так же просит авторизацию(или может что то еще надо добавлять?).
Вопрос такой: как Отключить Б-гомерзкую авторизацию на ftp? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ничего не забыл, то как-то так:

```
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='имя_вашего_FTP'].ftpServer.security.authentication.AnonimouseAuthentication.enabled:true
```

Ну, и следом раздать права:

```
appcmd set config имя_вашего_FTP /section:system.ftpserver/security/authorization /+[accessType='Allow',permissions='Read',roles='',users='*'] /commit:apphost
```

Не забудьте также выдать разрешение на чтение виртуальных папок:

```
appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /[name='имя_вашего_FTP'].ftpServer.directoryBrowse.showFlags:DisplayVirtualDirectories
```

Можно и через powershell, но там немного геморройнее. Но AppCmd появился, ЕМНИП, начиная с IIS7.